# Why does Handlebars think that my list is empty?

Tags: c#, .net, handlebars.net

Program is written in c# .net

```
  string mySource =
                @"<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>File Name</th>
                    <th>Error</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Testing</th>
                </tr>
                {{#each entry}}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{fname}}</td>
                        <td>{{error}}</td>
                        <td>{{size}}</td>
                        <td>{{data}}</td>
                        <td>test data</td>
                    </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </table>";

  var json = @"[
  {
    ""fname"": ""testFile1"",
    ""error"": ""true"",
    ""size"": 10,
    ""date"": ""02-15-2023""
  },
  {
    ""fname"": ""testFile2"",
    ""error"": ""false"",
    ""size"": 8,
    ""date"": ""01-15-2023""
  },
  {
    ""fname"": ""testFile3"",
    ""error"": ""true"",
    ""size"": 195,
    ""date"": ""08-23-2021""
  }
]";

var plz = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TemplateParams>>(json);


var template = Handlebars.Compile(mySource);
var result = template(plz);
```

As far as I can tell this should work but the program seems to think there is nothing in the list.  The only thing that prints are the headers that are hard coded in, and other than that nothing prints.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know

I've tried changing the templates and the objects I am passing into the templates, but I keep getting only the headers to print.

Comment: Will do and update post, I tried formatting it properly but clearly that did not work

Comment: What is the value of `plz` in the JavaScript? I am guessing it is an array of objects (`[ {}, {}, {} ]`), but the way you are calling your template it would need to be an object with an `entry` array: `{ entry: [ {}, {}, {} ] }`. I think your template should be `#each this`, not `#each entry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start of your `each` loop looks like this:

```
{{#each entry}}
```

The model that you provide to the rendering engine is just a collection, it doesn't have a property `entry`. Use `this` instead.

```
{{#each this}}
```

This means that you want to loop over the *whole* model - the `plz` variable you provide to `template()`, which is of type `List<TemplateParams>` - rather than a non-existent property of the List object.

Comment: Awesome, that worked.  I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help!